# assign true/false variable based on multple variables

Tags: python

Here is my assignment:

> Clunker Motors Inc. is recalling all vehicles from model years 1995-1998 and 2004-2006.Given a variable modelYear write a statement that assigns True to recalled if the value of modelYear falls within the two recall ranges and assigns False otherwise.
>
> Do not use an if statement in this exercise!

so if I'm reading this correctly:

I need to have a variable "recalled" that will be assigned true or false based on the condition of the variable modelYear being between 1995 and 1998 OR being between 2004 and 2006.

In doing some searching I found this segment of code someone else used for this challenge:

`recalled = ((modelYear >= 1995) And ((modelYear <= 1998)) Or (modelYear >=2004) And (modelYear <=2006))`

Now MyProgrammingLab is not accepting this as a valid answer to the situation. It say SyntaxError line 1. Am I just overlooking an open parenthesis or missing a capitalization or something? Or am I completely wrong in using this approach?

Comment: Is that all you have?

Comment: Well, try something out if this is indeed all you have.  Set the modelYear to something that will be true, then set recalled as you have.  Now below that make modelYear something that will be false and see what happens. Also lowercase the and/or.  Also it looks like there is an extra parenthesis in there

Comment: this is something I am finding I really dislike about the MyProgrammingLab activities, it's not expecting me to write a program it's just asking for a statement that meets the requirements. Like I get that it's trying to teach the concept over the application specifically... but yeah.

I was missing a parenthesis but even with that corrected it's still giving the same response.

Comment: I don't know what myProgrammingLab is but there are many things you could do without using an if. My guess it is a practice on some topic that was just discussed.  Use that approach

Comment: it's an online 'class' for programming made by TuringScraft. There are literally more words in this set of exercises than there are words in the section in the book it supposedly relates to. This is listed as 3.6: Decision Structures. Section 3.6 in the book is literally 3/4 of a page while there are 19 exercises in MyProgrammingLab.The entire chapter doesn't talk about other options for decision structures besides if/else and elif. Are there any online resources you could point me at that talk about other options?

Comment: You can look up alternatives to switch statements but it wouldn't make much sense here.  I think what you are doing seems ok.  Again, I can't really tell you what they want because I don't know.

Comment: forget about MyProgrammingLab for now. simply write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), add it to your question and restart from here. or just read your statement again and try to spot the missing character.

Comment: Rather than searching for the answer somewhere online, *think* about what the requirement is. You need a variable on the left and an expression on the right which will evaluate to `True` or `False` depending the the value of `modelYear`, start simply and build up. Googling != Learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close, but you are using the wrong tools.  I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), and run the code locally.  There are other IDEs which are excellent, but this is the one I use.  When I typed in this:

```
modelYear = 1997
recalled = ((modelYear >= 1995) And ((modelYear <= 1998)) Or (modelYear >=2004) And (modelYear <=2006))
```

PyCharm showed me:

[image]

Note the red underline for the syntax error, and when the cursor is hovered, it says 'Unresolved reference' because it does not know what `And` is.  It should be `and`.

> Better Tools == Better Code.

Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remember PEP8 rules which says,special reserved keywords are in lowercase,so its not **And,Or** but **and,or**

click on [pythonrules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

[Pep8 Rules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: PEP8 rules? Have not heard of those before.

Comment: @MichaelCividanes I thought you must be knowing PEP8 since you are coding in this language.I suggest you to read that once in a while.

Comment: @TheExorcist - It would be useful if you could quote the bit from PEP8 that states that

Comment: Its described as Pep8 rules in answer.I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Run your code locally - figure out your SyntaxError. Read the examples more carefully. And / Or are not capitalized.

Also, Python has a range function. You could use that instead

```
recalled = modelYear in range(1995, 1999) or modelYear in range(2004, 2007)
```

You use end year +1 because ranges are non-inclusive